# UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier what exactly is happening?

Tags: asp.net, claims-based-identity

Im doing claims based user role authentication. For this authentication i tested the following:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.StreetAddress, Address),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
},
```

My authentication works just fine, but the i realized that i should implement some kind of security in order to avoid that the user can tamper the set role.

Therefore i stumbled across this, that is supposed to be added in the `Global.asax`:

```
AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Email;
```

I can't seem to exactly understand what this code above does? Am i right, if i say that it gives the cookie, that the user holds, a unique token made from the `email`, that then is used to validate the legitimacy of the user by the system?

Im new to this, by the way, so go easy on me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're meaning by your question, but let me try to clear out a few things.

First, let's talk about your `AntiForgeryConfig` line of code. What it does is configure the [AntiForgeryToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470175(v=vs.118).aspx) to use the `Email` claim to identify the request (creates a token based on the email). The `AntiForgeryToken` allows you to trust a request and prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF).

It is implemented in 2 parts. First you need to add the `AntiForgeryToken` to the form (`@Html.AntiForgeryToken`). Second, you need to validate the token in your controllers' actions (`ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`).

[Here is a link to explain what CSRF](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/)

[Here is a link with up to date code how to implement it](http://peterkellner.net/2014/05/19/asp-net-mvc-forms-need-include-html-antiforgerytoken-security/)

As a side note, you said `... to avoid that the user can tamper the set role`. AntiForgeryToken doesn't do anything about tampering roles. Tampering roles would more related to your authentication process.